# EKS AWS: Can't connect Worker Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am a bit very stuck on the step of [Launching worker node in the AWS EKS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#eks-launch-workers). And to be honest, at this point, I don't know what's wrong. 
When I do kubectl get svc, I get my cluster so that's good news.
I have this in my aws-auth-cm.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::Account:role/rolename
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```

Here is my config in .kube

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: CERTIFICATE
    server: server
  name: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
    user: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
  name: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
current-context: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:region:account:cluster/clustername
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - clustername
      command: aws-iam-authenticator.exe
```

I have launched an EC2 instance with the advised AMI.

Some things to note :

- I launched my cluster with the CLI,
- I created some Key Pair,
- I am not using the Cloudformation Stack,
- I attached those policies to the role of my EC2 : AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,  AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly, AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy.

It is my first attempt at kubernetes and EKS, so please keep that in mind :). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file and auth file looks right. Maybe there is some issue with the security group assignments? Can you share the exact steps that you followed to create the cluster and the worker nodes?
And any special reason why you had to use the CLI instead of the console? I mean if it's your first attempt at EKS, then you should probably try to set up a cluster using the console at least once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the reason why I didn't do with the console is that it didn't work when I tried. I have a AD user and IAM user, I created with the console a cluster and never could get anything back from kubectl get svc. So I ressorted to using another IAM user account, but that has no console access (from what I have been said) and it worked with the CLI....  I think I might miss something with the permissions...

Comment: My IAM user account has those policies attached related to EKS stuff: EC2
Limited: List, Elastic Container Registry Full access, EKS Full access. I use the ADFS CloudAdmin, I do NOT have fullAccess right so everytime I need to do IAM things, I need to ask someone else (and I do not think I'll get this right)

Comment: I have looked on that IAM user, they have the policy AmazonEKSClusterPolicy and AmazonEKSServicePolicy attached so it might be why they can connect to the cluster...? Althought it works by cli but not console (as no console acces like I previously mentionned)

Comment: One possible reason for the worker nodes not showing up on your cli is maybe due to lack of permissions. By default, the user who created the cluster has access to the cluster and no one else.
Also, check if the AMI you used conforms with the version of K8s running on your cluster.

Comment: I realised as well that I didn't link the SG to an Internet Getaway (because it is just a trial and I didn't want to take risks)...

Comment: So did that solve the issue? And if you want to keep your workloads private, deploy your worker nodes in private subnets, and attach a NAT gw or instance to allow internet access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for whatever reason aws_auth configmap does not apply automatically. So we need to add them manually. I had this issue, so leaving it here in case it helps someone.

1. Check to see if you have already applied the aws-auth ConfigMap.

   `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth`

If you receive an error stating "Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "aws-auth" not found", then proceed

2. Download the configuration map.

   `curl -o aws-auth-cm.yaml https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/cloudformation/2020-10-29/aws-auth-cm.yaml`
3. Open the file with your favorite text editor. Replace <ARN of instance role (not instance profile)> with the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM role associated with your nodes, and save the file.
4. Apply the configuration.

   `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml`
5. Watch the status of your nodes and wait for them to reach the Ready status.

   `kubectl get nodes --watch`

You can also go to your aws console and find the worker node being added.

Find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)